# Slick slider - Navigate to slide on a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

Hello I got a question regarding using the slick slider on different pages. I want to be able whenever I click on a slide I navigate towards a different page and on that page I want to show for example the 3th slide.

To illustrate my question:

---

**Slick slider 1 - [index.html](http://www.wendyschaar.nl)**

A slick slider containing different reviews of clients. Look at the bottom of the page.

---

**Slick slider 2 - [testimonials.html](http://www.stefanperez.nl/testimonials)**
A slider containing a more detailed view of the reviews.

The desired behavior that I want is that whenever I press on slide within the index.html I can navigate towards the matching review on my  testimonial page.

Anyone any idea if this is possible? I was thinking of adding the following code to each slide:

```
<a href="testimonials?slide=5"></a>
```

But somehow that does not work.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to click on a link, then navigate to another page and have it appear at the content section you define? So if you had a slide which is number 5 and half way down the page that would show on the navigation change?

Comment: Exactly. I want to click on slide 5 of my slider in index.html and it will navigate for example to slide 3 within my testimonial page @Paddy

Comment: <a href="testimonials#slide5">link</a> add an anchor tag and do this for the native html way. or look at JQuery to pull the url  variables and passing it to a function to 'scroll to element'